# SQL LIKE repeating n times not-this-charachters [^*]

Tags: sql-like

We have a coding system for SKU which indicates the variants of an item.
The generic code is:

```
261/TEPU.x.x
```

The specific variants are something like:

```
261/TEPU.A.I
261/TEPU.Z.GS
```

How can I select in SQL all the variants of the code 261/TEPU.x.x ?
Note: x can be replaced by n characters

Example:
In a table I have the records:

```
261/NOOO.A.I
261/TEPU.A.I
261/TEPU.Z.GS
```

With:

```
SELECT        PERCENT Item
FROM            dbo.MA_Items
WHERE        (Item + ' ' LIKE '261/TEPU.[^*].[^*]')
ORDER BY Itemt
```

I obtain:
261/TEPU.A.I

With:

```
SELECT        TOP (100) PERCENT Item, Description, IC_InventoryDivision
FROM            dbo.MA_Items
WHERE        (Item + ' ' LIKE '261/TEPU.[^*].[^*][^*]')
ORDER BY Item
```

I obtain:

```
261/TEPU.Z.GS
```

How can I obtain both with just one SQL sentence ?

With regular expressions, I should simply add a + to indicate 1 or more times:

```
SELECT        PERCENT Item
FROM            dbo.MA_Items
WHERE        (Item + ' ' LIKE '261/TEPU.[^*]+.[^*]+')
ORDER BY Item
```

to obtain this:

```
261/TEPU.A.I
261/TEPU.Z.GS
```

I use Microsoft SQL server.

thank you